# Multi-line email body when sending emails from excel

Tags: vba, string, email, outlook

I am trying to automate sending emails with multiple lines and paragraphs through excel using VBA. Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub Send_Email()
Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
Email_Cc, Email_Bcc, Email_Body As String
Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant
Email_Subject = "test"
Email_Send_From = "email"
Email_Cc = ""
Email_Bcc = ""

Dim r As Range, cell As Range, mynumber As Long
Dim i As Long

Set r = Range("K2:K300")
i = 2

For Each cell In r
    If Cells(i, "K").Value = "" Then
    Else

        Email_Send_To = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,"K").Value
        Email_Body = "test from outlook excel"


        Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)

        With Mail_Single
            .Subject = Email_Subject
            .To = Email_Send_To
            .cc = Email_Cc
            .BCC = Email_Bcc
            .Body = Email_Body
            .send
        End With

    End If
    i = i + 1
Next
On Error GoTo debugs
debugs:
If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

However I'm not sure how to make the body of the email include line breaks and split up paragraphs rather than just having one block of text.

Comment: Use `VBnewline` for new line character

Comment: You can use HTML Body format and can use HTML tags such as para <p> and break <br/> tags in your email body.

Comment: @Pareseh J: The text is being sent from Excel to outlook why would he need <p> and </br>

Comment: @Jelly : Simply to have more control over the content you want to display, because HTML is far more powerful for that! But I agree, it isn't useful in most cases! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `VBNewLine` for a new line character.

```
Dim A As String: A = "Line A"
Dim B As String: B = "Line B"
Debug.print(A & VbNewLine & B)
```

Output:

```
Line A
Line B
```

Comment: You can also use `vbCrLf`, i.e. `Msgbox("Hello " & vbCrLf & " This is a second line.")`.  (Note sure if it works in `Debug.Print` but it should).

Comment: Just a warning here because I don't have the exhaustive list in my head, but not all of the "usual" characters to change line works in the body of an Outlook email. But if I remember well, both `vbNewLine` and `vbCrLf` should work properly!

Comment: I used vbnewline in the past to send template emails from Excel to Outlook and it works fine!